# javascript detect input field and show the message if the user has change something

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have form on my view page .. i am sending form through ajax .. i want to check if user has change some thing .. and if that condition returns true then i want to show the success message .. but right now when i have used **on** or **change** it is displaying the message write after change ...i want to show the message after the submit button has pressed

after the success of ajax

```
   var form_data = {
         name: $('#name').val(),
         email: $('#email').val(),
         password: $('#password-check').val(),
         oldpassword: $('#oldpassword').val(),
         timezone: $('#UserinfoTimezone').val(),
         alternate_email: $('#alternate_email').val(),
         newsletter: newsletter,


    };
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:form_data,

        url:"http://localhost/userinfo/settings/",

        success : function(data) {
     if (data=="1"){


             $('input').on('change', function(){
              $("#information").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);               

     });

      i want to show the message after the submit button ...
```

Comment: does the form have values? and you want to check if they are unchanged?

Comment: tried binding a click event in the submit button, or a onSubmit event on the form?

Comment: @Sergio  yes the form has the old values ..

Comment: On change isn't really well implemented. If I remember different browsers have implemented it in different ways. Don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Post some html also...

Comment: i have posted some code ...